# Why do I get NIL when passing a CoreData entity object to another view?

Tags: core-data, swiftui

This one is testing my patience, I simply want to pass a Coredata entity object to another view, but when I pass it on the sheet I get nil!!!

process:

1. save the entity object into a state var
2. pass the state var to a sheet modal

has anybody experienced this error? how did you fix it? do CData needs some special treatment?

writing some more stuff because stackoverflow doesn't let me post this question if I don't have enough text

[image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct TodayView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var viewContext
    
    @FetchRequest var fetchRequest: FetchedResults<ToDoItem>
    
    @EnvironmentObject var model: ContentModel
    
    @State var taskToEdit: ToDoItem? //tp pass tpo the item detail view
    
    @State var isPresented: Bool = false
    
    init() {
        _fetchRequest = FetchRequest<ToDoItem>(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \ToDoItem.timestamp, ascending: false)],predicate: NSPredicate(format: "today == true && done == false"))
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("Today").font(.title)
            List {
                ForEach(fetchRequest, id: \.self) { task in
                    Text(task.desc!)
                        .foregroundColor(task.done ? .white : task.today ? .white : .black)
                        .listRowBackground(task.done ? Color.green : task.today ? Color.blue : Color.white)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            taskToEdit = task
                            isPresented.toggle()
                        }
                        .swipeActions(allowsFullSwipe: true) {
                            Button(role: .cancel) {
                                task.done.toggle()
                                task.today = false
                                task.date_completion = Date()
                                
                                do {try viewContext.save()} catch {
                                    let nsError = error as NSError
                                    fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
                                }
                                
                                print("mark as done")
                            } label: {
                                Label("Done", systemImage: "checkmark")
                            }
                            .tint(.green)
                        }
                        .simultaneousGesture(LongPressGesture()
                            .onEnded { _ in
                                let impactMed = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .light)
                                impactMed.impactOccurred()
                                
                                task.today.toggle()
                                
                                do {try viewContext.save()} catch {
                                    let nsError = error as NSError
                                    fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
                                }
                                
                                
                                print("Loooong")
                                print(task.today)
                            }
                        )
                    
                }
                .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
                
                
            }
            .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
            .listRowInsets(.init(top: 4, leading: 8, bottom: 4, trailing: 8))
            .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented, onDismiss: {
                isPresented = false
            }) {
                itemDetail(taskItem: taskToEdit, textFieldText: taskToEdit!.detail!, isPresented: $isPresented)
            }
            
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: There is another `.sheet` API which takes an **item** as argument rather than a `Bool`. And `isPresented = false` is redundant, it's set to false automatically when the sheet is dismissed.

Comment: thanks, this fixed the issue SOMEHOW WTHECK!!, THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

i changed my sheet to as suggested by Vadian and it worked. what the heck!

```
            .sheet(item: self.$taskToEdit, content: { taskToEdit in
                itemDetail(taskItem: taskToEdit, textFieldText: taskToEdit.detail ?? "")
            })
```